# Styles for Vector layers on QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, topology, os-mastermap, habitat-modeling

I'm trying to do some habitat suitability modelling on QGIS. I've downloaded several vector maps from Ordinance Survey (OS). So far I've found a Cartographic stylesheet for  "OS VectorMap Local". This seems to work on Qgis. When I downloaded these there were GML style sheets which could be uploaded by going into properties --> style --> load style.(http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/OS_Styles)

However I also need other elements from a topographic OS MasterMap Layer and I can't find any styles that work for it.

I've found Styled Layer Descriptors (https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/styled-layer-descriptors.html). However when I downloaded it it was just text files and ".sld" files. Which I have no idea to use as a style in Qgis.

Any suggestions?

I don't think it should make a difference but I'm using a mac.

Using the comment below I added in a the sld style to the area and go this:
[image]

What I was expecting was something like this: (from the VectorMap style)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load the SLD styles in QGIS for layers.  I'm not very familiar with Ordinance Survey data, but it looks like you should be able to just import the SLD styles by going to the layer proprties -> Style -> Load Style -> select .sld option. Below are a couple of screen-shots that should help.

(This is just showing how to import the SLD styles - again, I'm not very familiar with the OS data, but hopefully the SLD styles should correspond with specific layers?)

[image: Layer Properties Dialogue]

[image: Load Style Dialogue]

Comment: Thankyou! I hadn't even realised that drop down was an option. However it doesn't seem to load properly. I've put a picture of the error in the original question ..

Comment: Glad that was of some help at least... if you give a link to the actual product you downlaoded and the sld file, I (or somebody else here) can try it and maybe give more input.  Otherwise, you might try the QGIS-User e-mail list... generally try to avoid cross-posting, but give it a day or two and mention this thread in the e-mail.

Comment: The link is the the original question (https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/styled-layer-descriptors.html) and it's the "OS MasterMap Topography Layer" that I've been downloading.

Comment: What's the QGIS user e-mail list and how do I use it?

Comment: Re: the data - right, that link location is where you can download the .sld files, but they need to be applied to a layer/set of layers. [This](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/topography-layer.html) seems to be a place to download the actual layers, albeit only a small sample is available for free (so it appears - again,  I don't typically deal w/ these data).  I downloaded a sample and tried applying the .sld styles, but not having success... so there's that... [Here's](http://lists.osgeo.org/listinfo/qgis-user) the link for the QGIS-user list.

Comment: Also, according to [this FAQ page](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/styled-layer-descriptor-faqs.html) a valid license seems to be required to use the sld styles... i guess look into it and e-mail qgis-user...

Comment: Thanks again. I'm a University student and get all the maps from edina/digimap meaning that all licensing should (as far as I'm aware) be covered.

Comment: Ok - then you might need to talk to local GIS folks at your university re the licensing. Best of luck on this!