# QGIS Styles for MassGIS data

Tags: qgis-3

Is anyone aware of a source for QGIS Style Libraries which mimic the MassGIS base map on their [Oliver mapping website](http://maps.massgis.state.ma.us/map_ol/oliver.php)?

I've poked around MassGIS, Github, and a general Google search and haven't located anything as of yet.

Comment: I guess you could try to create your own? Or simply ask the guy, if he'd share anything he has?

Comment: The SLD (Geoserver) Styles can be converted/imported to QGIS styles https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WMS+-+Styled+Layer+Descriptor+-+SLD > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168262/styles-for-vector-layers-on-qgis

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for that info! I got me going on the right track. I was trying to download data locally from the Metadata links in Oliver. Turns out there is a very handy WMS server which largely takes care of what I was hoping to do.